# Javascript - Jquery on the fly id retrieving

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've made a JS utility with jQuery that gives IDs to `div` elements and to links, which are coordinated.

Example:

```
div id="container"
div id="1"
div id="2"

div id="links"
a name="1"
a name="2"
```

So once the page is loaded, when I click on the first link (name="1") it is supposed to show the first div (id="1").

But it seems that as my IDs are created on the fly, the function doesn't seem to find the right div.

Here's my function:

```
$("#video_grid .grid_item a").each(
        function(i) {

            /* FINDING 'A' AND GIVING THEM NAME */

            $(this).addClass("item" + (i + 1));
            $(this).attr("name", "#" + (i + 1));

            /* BACKGROUND */

            $(this).css("background-image",
                    "url(images/visu_" + (i + 1) + ".jpg");
            $(this).hover(
                    function() {
                        $(this).css("background-image",
                                "url(images/visu_hover_" + (i + 1) + ".jpg")
                    },
                    function() {
                        $(this).css("background-image",
                                "url(images/visu_" + (i + 1) + ".jpg");
                    });
        });

/* FINDING DIV GIVING THEM IDS */

$("#capsule_player > div").each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass("item#" + (i + 1));
});

/* HERE'S THE PROBLEM */

$("#capsule_player div:first-child").css("display", "block");
/* appel la div correspondante avec la video */
$(".grid_item a").live("click", function() {
    var divname = $(this).attr("name");
    alert(divname);
    /* WORK FINE TIL HERE */

    /* THIS IS THE REAL PROBLEM */

    $(".item" + divname).show("slow").siblings().hide("slow");

    /* ALERT IF YOU FIND THE DIV WITH THE ID, DOES NOT WORK */

    if ($(".item" + divname)[0]) {
        alert('tonton');
    }

});
```

I'm using jQuery, basic HTML and CSS, and PHP is not allowed.

Comment: You seem to have a really cryptic intermix of ID's, names and classes. Try to order this a bit: classes group elements together, ID's identify one unique element on your page. Names are for form elements. Let none of them start with a number; for numbering you could use a seperate attribute of your own like `data-index="number"`. Once you have that, your code will be clearer and easier to debug.

Comment: What you call 'ID' is actually a class, hence the 'addClass' method name. Furthermore, I agree with Armatus. Finally, I can't see the problem from the code you posted, could you try and come up with a MINIMAL example HTML *and* JS that shows your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your function that is supposed to give the div's their IDs is giving them a class. You should change it to something like this:

```
$("#capsule_player > div").each(function(i){
    $(this).attr("id", 'item' + (i+1));
});
```

That *should* work, but the rest of the code could do with a tidyup as there a better/more semantic ways to do what you want to do (which I might do when I'm not busy).

**EDIT:**

Something like this would be better (based on Armatus' comment):

```
// give each div a data-index attribute
$("div.item").each(function(i){
    $(this).attr("data-index", i);
});

// give each anchor a data-index attribute
$("#video_grid .grid_item a").each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr("data-index", i);
});

$(".grid_item a").live("click",function () {
    var index = $(this).attr("data-index");

    $('div.item[data-index="' + index + '"]').show();
});
```

`.live()` is deprecated, but I'll leave it because I don't know which version of jQuery you're using.

Comment: Since OP is also actually selecting on class level as well, in the rest of the code, I don't think this will solve it.

Comment: He's selecting the div by the class *and* the `name` attribute on the `a`, so if the `name` attribute is an id selector (as defined at the start of the code), in theory, it should work. I haven't tested it though.

Comment: As I understand the code he/she is using the `name` of `a` (ie '#1') to construct a class selector '.name#1'. Oh wait, *there* actually lies the problem. The # sign can be used in a class' name, but as selector, it will act as ID selector. Anyway, your EDIT is a much better solution for the original underlying problem!

Comment: Wo, thank you, i'm trying your answers right away.
I've put the original code here :

http://jsfiddle.net/jBYBh/

Comment: ok, it works. Chris I just add to modifiy the last call for div.item, because there are no more div.item. I puted #capsule_player > div[data-index="' + divname + '"]. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Although the route that Christian shows you is probably in the long run better and surely more learningful, your original problem can easily be solved by changing two lines:

```
    $(this).attr('name', '#' + (i + 1));
    [...]
    $(this).addClass('item#' + (i + 1));
```

into

```
    $(this).attr('name', 'Q' + (i + 1));
    [...]
    $(this).addClass('itemQ' + (i + 1));
```

The immediate problem is that you are giving your div a classname which includes a '#' sign.  This will literally become part of your class name. However, during selection, this '#' sign will be interpreted as a 'ID' selector. So that doesn't work.